# Should I start Cubit then later on refactor the code to Bloc?

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

For the past week I have been learning the Bloc pattern. From that, I understand that I have 2 choices to use Cubit and Bloc. Cubit is for simple state, and Bloc is for complex state (that's my understanding between the two). Should I implement Cubit first then later on refactor it to Bloc? Or it all depends on the application?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131068/13470875

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Cubit and Bloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131067/what-is-the-difference-between-cubit-and-bloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to create a **Bloc** instead of the **Cubit**, but if it is for managing things like the theme or the language of the application, ..., to manage a simple state as you say, create a **Cubit** is fast,